# How to get USB 3.x power but with data limited to USB 2.0 HS?

Tags: usb, isolation, usb-device, usb-hub, architecture

I am designing a device with a few interesting requirements.  Due to power requirements, we need to draw 900mA, but due to isolation requirements, we're limited to the 480Mbps rate for our primary data path (our main microcontroller can't use superspeed lines).

My understanding is that there's no way to simply identify as a USB 2.0 device but pull 900mA from the USB 3.x port.  The tentative plan is to design the device such that there is a USB 3.x hub IC that interfaces with the PC, then two devices connected to it internal to the device: my 2.0 microcontroller (that wouldn't draw any power), and a 3.0 device (potentially looking like a charging device of some kind) to draw the 900mA.

Is there a simpler solution that I'm missing that would allow me to get the 2.0 data and 3.x power? And are there any pitfalls I'm not anticipating that I should prepare for?

Comment: Doesn't the USB 2.0 charging extension allow for up to 2.1 A out of a USB 2 connector?

Comment: I would use a USB 2.0 device controller/MCU but require the user to use a USB 3.0 port (Standard on Laptops/PCs these days). USB 2.0 devices work fine on a USB 3.0 Port with USB 2.0 Speeds. USB 3.0 ports allow for upto 900mA @ 5V. Power-Delivery negotiation should not limit the current to 500mA, if you specifie 900mA in the enumeration headers.

Comment: @Hearth I can't guarantee that the user will plug into a USB 2.0 port that specifically supports the battery charging spec.

Comment: @ElectronicsStudent From what I can tell, a device has to be "SuperSpeed" or USB 3.x in order to get the 900mA.  per the USB 3.0 spec (Nov 2008) "Depending on the power capabilities of the port to which the device is attached, a SuperSpeed device operating in SuperSpeed mode may be able to draw up to six unit loads from VBUS after configuration. The amount of current draw for SuperSpeed devices are increased to 150 mA for low-power devices and 900 mA for high-power devices when operating in SuperSpeed mode."

Comment: @mbengineer Hmmmmh "900mA ... when operating in SuperSpeed mode" is quite clear i guess. Maybe you can find some USB3.0 Power-Negotiation IC which also provides a USB2.0 Data-Path. Where is your isolation placed? Is it like Connector-Isolation (Data and Power) - MCU - Logic? ... or like Connector - MCU - Isolation - Logic? In the last case you could go with USB 3.0 Data/power.

Comment: if  you're only using D+ and D-, then your only presenting as 2.0 anyway. most sources will provide more than 500ma these days, regardless of what some spec says. you could always use 2 connectors, like portable dvd drives often do.